# How to start a function from normal text (not a button)

Tags: ionic4, angularjs-ng-click

I have a function that I can call from a button, but I need to call it from the text within a paragraph.

This works:

```
<ion-chip (click)="myFunc('text')">Do stuff</ion-chip>

  async myFunc(item: string) {
    const popover = await this.popoverCtrl.create({
      component: ClearConfirmPopoverPage,
      mode: 'md',
      componentProps: {
        dataItem: item,
      },
      cssClass: 'popover-width',
    });
    await popover.present();
  }
```

But this doesn't...

```
<p>I would like to <a (click)="myFunc('text')">link</a> like this. Or maybe like <a ng-click="myFunc('text')">this</a>?</p>
```

Everything I've tried results in text that simply doesn't do anything when clicked.

Comment: Maybe it is the popover which won't open. When you try to console.log() the text to the function without the popover, i'm certain the text will pass.

Comment: Tomas, I added ```console.log(item);``` to my function and it didn't give me anything. I assume ```<a ng-click="myFunc('text')">this</a>``` is the right way to call the function.

Comment: I just found my answer: ```<a (click)="myFunc('text')">this</a>```

Comment: Good that you figured it out! Can't see much difference with your question though ;)

Answer (score 0):

My colleague figured out how to call a function from an `<a>`: 
`<p>I just found my answer: <a (click)="myFunc('text')">this</a></p>`